# Mapping SDUI view IDs to Android View IDs

Tags: android, android-view

For an Android Server-Driven UI (sdui) client, how can we manage string view IDs that come from the server (e.g. id="last-name")? I'd like UI test code to be able to look for this "last-name" element, but Android view IDs need to be integers, and I don't want the client code to need to know server UI elements in advance (and create R.id.last_name). The options I can think of are

1. Have a mapping from "last-name" to integer, that the UI test code can leverage
2. Store "last-name" in some other view field (e.g. accessibility metadata looks workable)

Is anyone already doing this, that has a good solution? Thanks!

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: I'm not sure it can be made more specific, unfortunately. The SDUI tool I'm using is Beagle, but it really is a general problem - when view IDs are not controlled by the Android app, but instead server-driven UI response.